# Rails deployment can't find correct gem version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, rubygems

I'm doing my first deployment of a Rails app and using capistrano. The installation aborts with the following error:

```
*** [err :: plantality.com] RubyGem version error: will_paginate(2.2.2 not ~> 2.3.11)
```

but I've already vendored 2.3.11 to vendor/gems and have the following in my environment.rb (which google tells me is the correct thing to do):

```
config.load_paths += Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/gems/**"].map do |dir| 
  File.directory?(lib = "#{dir}/lib") ? lib : dir
end

config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.11', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
```

Comment: Just a side note, you don't need to specify gemcutter.org as a source...have you been to http://gems.rubyforge.org lately? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found the problem. I had made some changes to the environment.rb file and failed to commit them to SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `~>` from `:version`